# Adding any method or interface to classnode gives me an exception in java objectweb ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I am using objectweb ASM and im trying to add an interface to a class, but doing the following:

```
ClassNode clazz = new ClassNode();
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
cr.accept(clazz, 0);
clazz.interfaces.add("any/interface/Ever");
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
clazz.accept(cw);
return cw.toByteArray();
```

always gives me the exception:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize
```

it also happens if I try to add any method nodes to a classnode. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This exception is probably a "cascade" from another failure. You need to post more information. Catch any internal exception that might be causing this failure.

Comment: It is impossible to get that exception with the posted code. All this code does, is creating and filling a byte array

Comment: I would guess that you didn't include asm-tree in your .jar and somewhere lower there is caused by NoClassDefFoundError  / ClassNotFoundException. But you should post whole error